# Octave bode plot looks like a decade plot in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot

When I do a bode plot on a load over a simple LRC filter then compare graphing the frequency in OCT and DEC, I would expect their plot shapes would look different given OCT plots the x-axis in *1Hz,2Hz,4Hz,8Hz,16Hz,32Hz...* and DEC plots in a log scale *(1Hz,10Hz,100Hz,1kHz,10kHz,100kHz,1MHz,10MHz,100MHz)*

But when I generate the simulation, they had the same shape with 10Mhz and 100Hz align on the x-axis.

[image: OCT]
[image]

Comment: *they had the same shape with 10Mhz and 100Hz align on the x-axis.* - No they don't. Look at what you have posted. I also see that you haven't formally accepted an answer since 2014. Do you think that is fair?

Comment: @Andyaka, certainly not. My fault for not coming back for these answers.